# MySQL alphabetical ordering character limit, how to get around this?

Tags: mysql

I don't know if this is an actual thing, I noticed my paginated search break at a particular offset. There are no errors, and it seems the cause is two rows one after another, that have very similar names. I'm ordering alphabetically and when I set the offset around these two rows eg. the two rows occur at 151, 152. Actually this might sound contradicting but it also breaks at 150. My limit is 30, so if I do 150, 30 at the end of my SQL SELECT UNION ALL statement, nothing comes out. Setting it to 153,30 though, all the rows appear.

The two names that are similar are like this:

```
abcdefgh ijklmnop ####### #####
abcdefgh ijklmnop qrstuvw xyzabc
```

Further down the line there are other rows which are similar as well but not nearly as long as the top for example:

```
abcdefghi j##
abcdefghi j##
```

That's why I think this could be the cause, it's only these two rows/area.

Line 150 is completely different though and I think it's just because I included it, If I do 150, 1 to limit only the row #150

It works

What is the deal with this?

edit: ahhh actually though I went into the table and changed the names to be completely different and it still seems to break at those two rows... what does this mean I wonder.

edit: it actually seems to be a JSON problem though I don't know why... how? When I do var_dump the array is built.

There is this weird character in one row, it's like a question mark in a diamond.

**strong text**

Oh it became that when I tried to paste it in here, I'll remove that character and see if that helps.

edit: Yeah that was the problem, it was an apostrophe, for some reason it became this questionmark in a black diamond.

edit: I guess it's not an apostrophe problem, it must be like a text editor format or something, because when I pasted the apostrophe from MySQL (copied in phpmyadmin from editing row) and pasted it here it became that strong text line above.

But now when I typed an apostrophe, saved, and edited/copied again:

'

It's just a regular apostrophe, no diamond either. hmm

Comment: It sounds like problem with character encoding.

Comment: You have some multi-byte characters, and you haven't specified the correct collation, or you're using the wrong charset in the HTML file.

Comment: The html uses utf-8, it was just that one row with this character: �

Comment: It was stored as an apostrophe in the table but it appears as that when displayed on a page.

Comment: I just want to know what sort of catch to write for this so I don't get an entire blank page in the pagination.

Comment: It's probably a Unicode quote rather than an ASCII apostrophe.

Comment: You need to specify the appropriate collation in the MySQL table.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I didn't fill in these tables. It seems like it just occured in that one instance because other tables/rows have apostrophes and no problem, that's why I think it was from a text-editor or it was copied from a website or something and put into the title field of the insert form. Anyway thanks for your time.